# Setting Origin without affecting location of linked duplicates

Tags: modeling, linked-data, origin

Presently working through a tutorial, and I have realized that I have inadvertently made a buttload of linked duplicates of a mesh object with an origin out in the middle of nowhere. The origin in this instance is needed to locate more of these objects in the future (by moving origin to the 3D cursor). When I try and correct this mistake by setting origin, all of my linked duplicates shift (not ideal). so as part of my learning journey  I have two questions:

1. Is there anyway to update origin point of a mesh without having all the linked models jump around?
2. In the event one can't do that, what would be a recommended practice to deal with this issue? (aside from not forking it up in the first place :P)

I hope that's clear, if not happy to clarify anything!

Thanks,

Nathan

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oh! Well I've accidentally figured it out!

1. Set your 3D cursor location.
2. Make sure you have the linked object selected that relates to the location of your 3D cursor.
3. select all linked objects (easy method is to go Select > Select Linked > Object Data
4. Set Origin to 3D Cursor (right click > Set origin)

It should update all linked objects simultaneously.

Not sure if answering your own question is encouraged here, but I thought it might benefit others :)

Comment: Yes, answering your own question is definitely encouraged here. You can even accept your own answer as the correct one, so other users can see there is a working solution to the problem. I think there is a grace time period of 48 hours before you can accept your own answers - that is for the reason, if you maybe just have a workaround and someone else could come up with a better solution, an already accepted answer might keep others from looking into the problem. But you can change an accepted answer later on, you don't have to stick with our decision if there suddenly is a better solution.